# How to do a sum in R that gives the result in only one row

Tags: r

So I have a dataset in R of 1380 observations, with a dummy variable that is coded as 1 if the individual is rich. I would like to sum all the individuals with a value of 1 in the dataset, but whenever I create a new variable that sums its values with:

```
dataset_union$sum_high<- sum(dataset_union$high_inc)
```

The new variable it creates repeats the result of the sum over and over for every observation in the dataset. I would like this variable to show the result of the sum only in the first row, and leave blank the spaces below.

How could I code it?

Comment: You can create a logical vector `sum(dataset_union$high_inc==1)`

Comment: Thanks for your help!That gives me the correct result, but it doesn't store it in the dataset as a new variable that indicates this result only in the first row, which Is what I need

Comment: Just assign to new column `datset_union$newcolumn <- sum(dataset_union$high_inc==1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
dataset_union[1, "sum_high"] <- sum(dataset_union$high_inc == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following conditional operator `==`

Example:

```
ID <- c(1:10)
individuals <- c(1,1,2,1,5,3,3,2,1,6)
df <- data.frame(ID, individuals)
sum(df$individuals == 1)
4
```